# Delete the last input row in Python

Tags: python, input, console

I have the following code:

```
num = int(raw_input("input number: "))
print "\b" * 20
```

The console output looks like

```
input number: 10
```

I'd like to delete the text `input number: 10` after the user presses `ENTER`. The backspace key `\b` can't do it.

Comment: which operating system do you work under?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work in most unix and windows terminals ... it uses very simple ANSI escape.

```
num = int(raw_input("input number: "))
print "\033[A                             \033[A"    # ansi escape arrow up then overwrite the line
```

Please note that on Windows you may need to enable the ANSI support using the following
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/windowstips/windows2000/usertips/miscellaneous/commandinterpreteransisupport.html

"\033[A" string is interpreted by terminal as move the cursor one line up.

Comment: I tried your code, but the row is still there (e.g. when I input number 10) it looks as follows: "input number:       0"
"Done" and cursor is below it.

Comment: Are there enough spaces at the end of your string? Notice there is heaps of spaces at the end of my line.

Comment: So the 1 is erased but the 0 is not?

Comment: Yes, I understand it that you have overwritten the text, but I want to remove the whole text "input number: X" and move the cursor in front of "input" (which should already be deleted.)

Comment: Modified to erase the whole line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11976/discussion-between-maria-zverina-and-xralf)

Comment: thanks. I works now, could you please explain the character `[A` yet?

Comment: The following string "\033[A" means put cursor one line up.

Comment: You can also use a library like termcolor to avoid manual escape code formatting.

Comment: Use `\033[K` to erase to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

print "Welcome to a humble little screen control demo program"
print ""

# Clear the screen
#screen_code = "\033[2J";
#sys.stdout.write( screen_code )

# Go up to the previous line and then
# clear to the end of line
screen_code = "\033[1A[\033[2K"
sys.stdout.write( screen_code )
a = raw_input( "What a: " )
a = a.strip()
sys.stdout.write( screen_code )
b = raw_input( "What b: " )
b = b.strip()
print "a=[" , a , "]"
print "b=[" , b , "]"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are control sequences for 'word back' and 'line back' and the like that move the cursor. So, you could try moving the curser back to the start of the text you want to delete, and overriding it with spaces. But this gets complicated very quickly. Thankfully, Python has the standard [curses module](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) for "advanced terminal handling".

The only issue with this is that it isn't cross-platform at the moment - that module has never been ported to Windows. So, if you need to support Windows, take a look at the [Console module](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm).

Comment: Would you know which functions from `curses` module would be helpful?

Comment: @xralf you will want to create `window` object by calling `curses.initscr()`, and get do your I/O using the window methods rather than `print` and `raw_input`. Then when you want to delete an entire line, you need to ensure that the cursor is somewhere on that line, and call `.deleteln()` on the window.

Answer (score -3):

You can use os module

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

The "cls" and "clear" are commands which will clear a terminal (ie a DOS prompt, or terminal window).

For IDLE:The best you could do is to scroll the screen down lots of lines, eg:

```
print "\n" * 100
```

Comment: I know this command, but I'd like to remove only the text "input number: X" because the text above should not be removed.

Comment: Why do need to remove that...whats your exact requirement?

Comment: I'm reading interactively in a loop and don't want to have much text on the terminal. Explaining the whole context would be for long and off topic.