# how do I keep my input at the same screen location?

Tags: python

My current input method is a for loop. I input an integer it gets added to a list then it goes around to the next input. This produces a new line each time it goes around. I would like to keep the input entries at the same location. I'm new to Python and programming in general so I have no clue where to start. My input statement is in this form:

```
var= input(" message: ")
```

Thank You

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `I would like to keep the input entries at the same location`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with UNIX or Windows terminals, you can add an ASCI escape (`"\033[A"`) to move the cursor one line up to ask for input again, as shown in the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829650/delete-the-last-input-row-in-python), so in this way, you can get your input message at the same position by "overwriting" the previous input message.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: there's a reason most simple applications don't do this: it's a lot of work for not very much payoff.

If you're talking about making sure that the `"message: "` line always appears in the same place in the window, then you can't do it with plain [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input): it doesn't take an "end of line" argument and actually the newline happens before input gets a hold of the input string. (I.e. when the user hits `RETURN`.)

You *can* do it, especially if you don't care about Windows, using `getch` mode, which basically says that the terminal passes *characters* to you, not whole lines, and you need to decide how to interpret them. The [getch package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch) seems like it might be able to help here, it even supports Windows!

Another option (probably not as effective or a nuclear bomb when what you need is a scalpel) would be to use something like curses or [blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/1.5.1)' terminal.location abilities. And blessings, I believe, incorporates ANSI escape chars. (As mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19648314/25616) to this question, it's probably the right way to go.)