# python remove input() from command prompt

Tags: python, windows, input

I'm trying to remove input from the console after using input(). I am on Windows using Python and I have searched on SO but vt100 codes will not work. After input is given and enter is pressed I then want to go up a line and remove the input.

I also tried the information here: [Delete the last input row in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829650/delete-the-last-input-row-in-python)

But it did not remove the users input and instead printed <-[A on a newline

Comment: If you need user interaction with your app,  you should consider changing your code to use a GUI , based on Tkinter or other portable tolkit (gtk+, QT+) - doubly so in Windows, where user proficiency  on the terminal is diminished.

Comment: I think what you want to do is not possible under windows if you use the `cmd` command. There are other shells like powershell and cygwin. Have a try with these.