# Print loop to the same line in terminal

Tags: python

Here is some code. it should be self explanatory. but anyways here we go.

```
   try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)
        print "password is:  %s" % password
        break;
   except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print "wrong: %s" % password
```

All works fie except instead of it printing lines like

```
wrong: pass
wrong: pass
wrong: pass
```

Is it possible to print on the same line until a password match is found?

Answer (score 3):

In python, a `,` at the end of print statement, prevents a line break, thus preventing the next text from printing in new line. So,

```
  try:
    smtpserver.login(user, password)
    print "password is:  %s" % password
    break;
  except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print "wrong: %s" % password,
```

This will print all text in same line, until the password is right

Comment: @MichaelDarnell: Happy to have helped. Feel free to accept my answer if it was of use to you.

Comment: is there a way to print just once over the original?

Comment: i get   wrong wrong.   i want it just wrong  once    until the pass is found     then print found   if that makes since?

Comment: @MichaelDarnell: I think this will do good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829650/delete-the-last-input-row-in-python

Comment: i replaced "wrong: %s" with just    "."    and that looks pretty simple and nice.  thanks for the help