# How to remove blank input entry with python

Tags: python, loops, input

How do I remove the empty input line after pressing enter.

```
temp = input('Enter temperature: ')
if temp == '':
    break
temp = int(temp)
temp_list.append(temp)
```

the if temp == '': when enter is pressed will produce "Enter temperature: " with no entry (obviously) I would like to work out that when enter is pressed the input prompt is removed and nothing will be shown and the program moves on to the next loop.

the code displays if i dont input anything and just press enter:

```
Enter temperature: 
Enter windspeed: 
Enter current humidity(0-100): 
Average temperature: No info on temperature
Maximum wind speed: No info on wind speed
Current humidity: No info on humidity
```

I want it to display this when i do nothing and just press enter:

```
Average temperature: No info on temperature
Maximum wind speed: No info on wind speed
Current humidity: No info on humidity
```

full code:

```
temp_list = []
wind_list = []
humid_list = []


while True:

    temp = input('Enter temperature: ')
    if temp == '':
        break

    temp = int(temp)
    temp_list.append(temp)


while True:

    wind_speed = input('Enter windspeed: ')
    if wind_speed == '':
        break

    wind_speed = int(wind_speed)
    wind_list.append(wind_speed)
    if wind_speed <= -1:
         break

while True:

    humid = input('Enter current humidity(0-100): ')
    if humid == '':
        humid_list.append(humid)
        break

    humid = int(humid)
    humid_list.append(humid)

    if (humid <= -1 or humid >= 101):
        break

if len(temp_list) == 0:
    print('Average temperature: No info on temperature')

else:
    avg_temp = sum(temp_list) / len(temp_list)
    print('Average temperature:', int(avg_temp))

if len(wind_list) == 0:
    print('Maximum wind speed: No info on wind speed')

else:
    print('Maximum wind speed:', max(wind_list))


if humid_list[0] == '' or humid_list[0] <= -1 or humid_list[0] >= 101:
    print('Current humidity: No info on humidity')

elif humid_list[-1] <= -1 or humid_list[-1] >= 101:
    print('Current humidity: ', humid_list[-2])

else:
    print('Current humidity:', humid_list[-1])
```

this is the code ran a few times and it works. just trying to get rid of the entry if nothing is inputed.
[Picture of IDLE showing no issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cNzO.png)

Comment: Please post code that actually runs, this one has a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Are you running this in `while True` loop?

Comment: @amanton there are a couple other problems with your code

Comment: I pasted full code. and i am getting no errors when running what I posted with IDLE.

Comment: i edited the post to try and clarify better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete the last input row in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829650/delete-the-last-input-row-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the comparative operator == rather than the assignment operator =

Comment: that was a mistake on my part, figuring out how to format the post into the code blocks i was typing rather than copy and paste. it was initially ==