# Delete the input line right after input has been sent

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, output

I'm looking for a good way to hide input entered for a chat-like system on WIndows

For now, i wrote this

```
import sys

name = input("Enter your message: ")
sys.stdout.write('\r')
print(message)
```

But it doesn't do anything.

I'd like to do something like this

```
Enter your message: Hello

Output:
Hello
```

That is way better then

```
Enter your message: Hello

Output:
Enter your message: Hello
Hello
```

So the final output, after some messages will be

```
Hello
How are you?
I'm fine thanks.
```

And not

```
Enter your message: Hello
Hello
Enter your message: How are you?
How are you?
Enter your message: I'm fine thanks.
I'm fine thanks.
```

I've seen some questions like mine before asking but i didn't find anything working, i also can't use `os` because it has to contain more inputs, i also tried using `\r` but (as i used it) doesn't do what i want it to do, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to *erase* the entire "Enter your name" line after the user has completed the input…?

Comment: Please upload your code.

Comment: Yes i want to erase the  "Enter your name" line and the actual input

Comment: I uploaded my code

Answer (score 1):

This is now a year old, but I faced the same issue and I think what you'd be looking for is using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Specifically, I used '\033[1A' and '\033[K', I don't have as much experience on them but as far as I can tell they're really good for specific manipulations like this.

'[1A' would be used to go on the line above and '[K' to erase everything on the line. So if you were to print out your "Enter your message: " from your input function, save your text in a variable, use the escape codes and then print your text, I believe you'd get the desired result.

Here I made an infinite texting loop where you can get what I believe is what you're looking for:

```
while True:
    text = input("Enter your message: ")
    print('\033[1A' + '\033[K', end='')
    print(text)
```

From here on you can do all kinds of manipulation/validation of your text and such, for example a specific condition for breaking the loop.

While I was looking for an answer I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736217/python-deleting-input-line) and bashBedlam's answer is particularly useful. They mention ANSI escape codes will not work the same on all terminals though, so it might be worth looking into if this is the solution you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do so if you are using command prompt to run your code;

```
from os import system
name = input('Enter your name: ')
system('cls')
print(f'Your name is {name}')
```

`system('cls')` clears the console after the input has been submitted as it is run immediately after the input is provided.

If you are using mac;

```
system('clear')
```

Comment: As i said, i can't use os because it has to contain more input and prints, and if i use it it will erase everything, i'm looking for a way to erase only that line and not the entire program

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just hide the user input you could use the builtin getpass module. This is designed for passwords so it will not display what the user types on the terminal.

```py
>>> import getpass
>>> name = getpass.getpass(prompt="name: ")
name:
>>> print(name)
Chris
```

Comment: I'm not trying to hide the input, i need to hide the entire input line right after input is submitted

Comment: You might want to change the title of the question as it says "Hide entered input"

Comment: It explains itself in the description, i guess the title is not wrong

Comment: explains it so well that two answers dont meet your requirement and the questions is downvoted......Maybe not as well as you think.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first question here

Comment: We all want to help you. So you want to delete the entire line which has the text about what to input and what the user types? is this on a specific OS? or has to be portable to work across a variety of OS

Comment: I re-wrote my question, now it says for good what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
import os
l = []
def main():
    empty = ""
    while True:
        message = input("Enter message: ")
        os.system("cls")
        if message == empty or message.isspace() == True:
            break
        l.append(message)
    print("Output:")
    for i in l:
        print(i)
main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).