# Want to clear the previous line on terminal in a timer program (python)?

Tags: python, terminal

So i have a code of a timer and When a person puts in the number i just want the timer to start and inputted number to not be visible.Code is something like

```
s=int(input("enter time in sec"))
countdown(s)
```

so the output is :

```
enter time in sec 5
0:4
0:3
0:2
0:1
0:0
time up
```

What i want is to first remove "enter time in sec 5" then when 0:4 prints i want to print 0:3 in its place not below it.

I tried [Python deleting input line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736217/python-deleting-input-line) and copy pasted this on the code like so

```
s = int(input("enter time in sec "))
print ('\033[1A\033[K')
countdown(s)
```

and nothing seemed to happen, don't if im wrong in the implementation or it didn't work.

Edit:-

Tried both

```
os.system('cls')
```

and

```
print ('\033[1A\033[K')
```

neither seemed to work

my code,

```
 def time_format(inp):
          import os
          m,s=divmod(inp,60)
          #os.system('cls')
          print ('\033[1A\033[K')
          ...code for printing time below...
```

Edit:- im on windows and am using Idle.
neither of the two work

Answer (score 0):

See accepted answer of: [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

`os.system('cls')` works on Windows, while
`os.system('clear')` works on Linux

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what OS you use but if you target Linux it could
be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time


def countdown(seconds):
    for i in range(seconds, -1, -1):
        # move to the beginning of the line and remove line
        print("\r\033[K", end='', flush=True)
        print(f"\r{i}", end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("\nTime's up!")


s = int(input("enter time in sec: "))
# move one line up
print("\033[1A", end='', flush=True)
countdown(s)
```

It works like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got a pop saying I shouldn't delete answered question therefore answering it myself.
I believe both the

```
print("\033[1A", end='', flush=True)
```

and

```
os.system('cls')
```

works. The issue is  that there is no option/method to do it on IDLE. because i tried both the methods work if i double click and run the file as is but none work on IDLE