Deleting an input line after it has been printed on the Terminal
I want to write a program using Python in which looks something like this-
text = input("Enter an integer:")

But as soon as the user enters an integer and clicks Enter, the entire line gets deleted. Then, I would like to add another line in it's place.
I know about \r, and how it can be used to get to the beginning of a line, but am not sure how to proceed from there onwards. I also don't want the input to be written over the line, Enter an integer in this case.
I'm using a MacOS Terminal with a zsh shell.

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59737913/18179479 Basically: print ('\033[1A' + '\033[K')

The answer depends on which terminal you are using. Python simply writes bytes to standard output; the terminal gets to decide how to render those bytes. Usually, you use something like the curses package, which implements terminal-specific solutions for various terminals, as long as you tell your program which terminal is being used.

One workaround would be to follow your input() with a print() statement that begins with the special character \0331A which returns to the start of the previous line in the console, followed by \033[K which erases the line until its end. Then you can proceed with any other printing you want to do:
text = input("Enter an integer:")
print('\033[1A', '\033[K', end='')
print('Some new text')

To explain what is happening, we are using ANSI escape codes to control the console. The special character \033 (ESC) takes parameters as documented here. We are using it twice:

\033[1A - the parameter is 1A. The A means to move the cursor up some number of rows, and 1 is that number.
\033[K - the parameter is K. This command erases from the cursor position to the end of the row.


There are two ways to fix it, 1: use carriage return (\r); 2: use backspace escape sequence (\b).
To explain carriage return and the backspace sequence, you have to understand that text printed using a somewhat another cursor, the input() function tells the cursor to print what ever comes from the keyboard, while print() directly tells the cursor to output text. Anyway, the backspace sequence moves the cursor back 1 char, and if anything comes after it in the string; it will overwrite it. The carriage return is the same, except it moves the cursor to the beginning of the line its' in.
In your case, I would do:
text = input("Enter an integer: ")
print("\b\r" + (" " * 50) + "\r")

The code above should do what you wanted. If the user input is long; then change 50 to a bigger number.
Another thing, it might not work on the python shell, so run the program in another console.

\b\r isn't really any different from \r alone.

No it is, because part of the question was "Then, I would like to add another line in it's place", and the carriage return does half of the job. So adding the backspace sequence is important.

\b moves the cursor back one space. \r moves it to the beginning of the line, regardless of where the cursor starts. It's the difference between "move left one, the move left all the way" and "move left all the way"

Print() moves the cursor to a new line automatically, so to delete the input text, that needs to be undone with the backspace sequence. Without it, the statement would print 50 spaces on a blank line, and again, the backspace would make it do that in the line before.

\b does not backspace over the preceding newline.

It wont do anything at all if you're running your program in python SHELL, so try using your cmd on windows or LXTerminal on linux or something

I've tried both Terminal and iTerm2 on macOS. What are you using that that indicates \b will back up to the previous line?

Well, actually i know it works in C++, because when i saw this post, i assumed python knew what \r and \b means. But it should, especially on windows cmd prompt because that's where i rum my C++ programs (and it works).

It has nothing to do with the language you are using; \b is U+0008 everywhere. What matters is how your terminal renders that character, and as we've established, not all terminals do so the same.

(So I'll modify my first comment: \b\r is not necessarily different from \r alone.)
