# I want to clear the input from the command line

Tags: python

```
def send():
    data = input()
    print("Server:",data)
    c.send(data.encode())
```

I'm making a messenger and want to have names before their messages. But I cant find a way to clear the input that they type before so messages start repeating. I tried using \r but it doesn't seem to work with inputs and I cant find modules that could clear the specific line.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want it to show on the screen before and after? I think you may want to print an [ANSI escape sequence](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) that moves the cursor up and to the start of the line. For instance, `print("hello"); print("\033[A\033[100D\033[K", end=""); print("world")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete the last input row in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829650/delete-the-last-input-row-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `input()` function an argument which will be placed before the actual input.

```
def send():
    data = input("Server:")
    c.send(data.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it to look like this:

```
bob: hey
msg> how are you?
```

When the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should change to:

```
bob: hey
bob: how are you?
```

You can do this with [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) on supported terminals.

```py
data = input("msg> ")
# when the user hits enter, the cursor moves down a line and to the first column
print("\033[A", end="")  # move the cursor up a line
print("\033[K", end="")  # erase the line
print("bob:", data) # print something new in the place of the input
```

Comment: I got a better terminal which accepts ANSI and it works so thank you.